Data not ready in time
I have a line of code which is triggered on the change of a radio button however I'm having to click twice on the radio button in order for the code to execute correctly
partyTypeChanged (index: number) {
  this.payAttributes[index].partyType = this.testForm.get('payReasons')['controls'][index].get('partyType').value;
}

HTML
  <form-radio
    formControlName="partyType"
    [formStatus]="testForm.formErrors.payReasons[i]"
    [parentFormGroup]="payReasonForm"
    [data]="{
      name: 'partyType',
      label: 'party type',
      options: [
        {
          name: individualThirdPartyValue,
          label: 'individual'
        },
        {
          name: entityThirdPartyValue,
          label: 'business'
        }
      ]
    }"
    (valueChanged)="partyTypeChanged(i)">
  </form-radio>

  <p *ngIf="payAttributes[i].partyType === individualPartyValue">individual</p>
  <p *ngIf="payAttributes[i].partyType === entityPartyValue">business</p>

I was able to get it to work with a setTimeout but I want to find out if anyone has an idea how else I can get it to work without using a setTimeout
This works
partyTypeChanged (index: number) {
  setTimeout(()=>{
    this.payAttributes[index].partyType = this.testForm.get('payReasons')['controls'][index].get('partyType').value;
  }, 3000); 
}


could you share more code like the html, if possible a simple .stackblitz with the issue happening

This could mean that the rest of the form gets updated with an event handler that also executes on a change of the radio button, but executes after this one. In that case, try to deal with all of this in one event handler, not several.

I'm guessing, you might be using (click) instead of (change) for radio button

I added html. It's not easy to put on stackblitz as there are a lot of dynamic values. I simplified as much as possible here

better you can subscribe for partyType valuechanges like partyType.valueChanges.subscribe

you can wrap the code in something like window.requestAnimationFrame so you shouldn't need as long of a timer
